# unable to access a service from another pod, using xmlhttprequest object

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

So, I wrote an API that is listening on the the path `/api/v1/books` and is deployed as a deployment on my k8s cluster, created service (`restapi-service`) so that we can call that from another pods. 
Now I created another deployment (`restapi-ui-deployment`) that just  has a `.html` page and and its being deployed on nginx, which eventually calls the the service that we have created earlier to get the response. 
Now, the issue is when I exec into the pods of `restapi-ui-deployment` I am successfully able to curl `http://restapi-service:8081/api/v1/books`. But if  we are trying to do the same thing from .html page that is deployed I get

```
GET http://restapi-service:8081/api/v1/books net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Below is the code that is being deployed as `restapi-ui-deployment`

```
if (xmlObj != null){
      xmlObj.open("GET", "http://restapi-service:8081/api/v1/books", true)
      xmlObj.onreadystatechange = processResponse;
      xmlObj.send(null)
    }
    else{
      console.log("There was an error getting the object.")
    }
    function processResponse(){
      if (xmlObj.status == 200 && xmlObj.readyState == 4){
        console.log("Got the response successfully")
        response = xmlObj.responseText
      }
      else{
        console.log("There was an issue getting the response.")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you defined `restapi-service` properly. ALso what is the output of `kubectl get svc` is it created properly.

Comment: @mchawre, If I am able to curl that service from another pod, simply means the service is defined properly and accessible right.

Comment: Yeah but it dependents on how you curl. `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` means there is some problem with service name resolution.

Comment: Try to `nslookup restapi-service.namespace.svc` from another pod.

Comment: @mchawre nslookup seems to be working
```
 nslookup restapi-service.webapp.svc
Server:  10.96.0.10
Address: 10.96.0.10#53

Name: restapi-service.webapp.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.107.244.184
```

Comment: Use that exact name in your api `xmlObj.open("GET", "http://restapi-service.webapp.svc:8081/api/v1/books", true)`

Comment: `http://restapi-service.namespace.svc:8081/api/v1/books` isnt working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you are confused about the way your application works. The XmlHttpRequest is originating in a webbrowser, therefore outside of the kubernetes cluster, not from nginx inside your cluster. (nginx serves the html page)
The kubernetes dns is not available outside of kubernetes, nor would a connection to  a ClusterIP work from the outside.
Solution: Create an appropriate Ingress and call that from your frontend or provide a proxy on your nginx where you got the frontend delivered. (That would lead to really getting the request origin as your nginx)

Comment: so I agree with you on that ingress solution, and thats working fine  for me. I was thinking if I am able to curl to a service from a pod and nginx is deployed on the same pod I should be able to query that service using `xmlhttprequest` as well.

Comment: okay, so the request that is being made is not from the nginx that is there in that pod, the request is being made from browser that what you are saying I think, and then yes that resolves my confusion I think. Lets I write some server side that IS being run in nginx, then I would be able to do that same right?

Comment: It would work, if you would run the browser inside a pod, since then the internal cluster dns would work. If you run the curl not in a pod but on your local machine it is effectively the same as an xmlhttp request in a browser