# Cannot make request from react pod to service pods

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running react frontend and golang backend in local minikube cluster via helm. This is a basic client-server architecture based system. When frontend calls for the backend request doesn't reach to the backend.
Error preview:
`Failed to load resource. The server with the specific hostname could not be found`.
Headers:

```
Summary
URL: http://service-two/v1/admin/languages/json/en
Status: —
Source: —
Initiator: 
request.js:150


Request
Origin: http://_._._._:30211
Referer: http://_._._._:30211/
Accept: */*
__

Response
No response headers
```

`Dockerfile` for frontend.

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`nginx.conf` for the react

```
server {
  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
  }

  location /v1/auth {
    proxy_pass http://service-one:8000/;
  }

  location /v1/admin {
    proxy_pass http://service-two:8000/;
  }
}
```

`configmap.yaml` for frontend

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "name" . }}-config
  labels:
    app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    component: "{{ .Values.service.name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
data:
  default.conf: |-
    window.config = {
      frontend: {
        main_panel: "{{ .Values.frontend.mainPanel }}"
      },
      backend: {
        service_one: "{{ .Values.frontend.serviceOne }}",
        service_two: "{{ .Values.frontend.serviceTwo }}"
      }
    }
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` details

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

I can `curl` from frontend to backend without any issue. It seems nginx reverse proxy doesn't seems to be working. How should I fix this?

Comment: nginx is running as pod in the cluster?

Comment: No nginx server running inside the react pod

Comment: content of `/etc/resolv.conf` file from nginx pod

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348029/unable-to-access-a-service-from-another-pod-using-xmlhttprequest-object

Comment: If the React application is making the request you show initially, it's running in the browser and not in Kubernetes, so you can't directly access `server-two` that way.  You need to target the nginx service or your cluster ingress.

Comment: @DavidMaze You mean exposing the service port to outside and calling like `http://minikube-ip:PORT/` ?

Comment: What URL are you using to launch the application in the first place?  Given the nginx config you show you should be able to use that same host name, or a relative URL `/v1/admin` without a host name part at all.